# Header-only and static build with QMake

Tags: c++, qmake

I am trying to set up a simple class that can be used both as a header only and static with qmake. I am contolling if the build is static using a macro "STATIC_BUILD" defined in the .pro file.

foo.pro:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += c++11

CONFIG += STATIC_BUILD

STATIC_BUILD {
    DEFINES += STATIC_BUILD
}

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp

HEADERS += \
    foo.h

STATIC_BUILD {
    SOURCES += \
        foo.cpp
}
```

foo.h

```cpp
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

#ifndef STATIC_BUILD
#define MY_INLINE inline
#else
#define MY_INLINE
#endif

class Foo {
public:
    Foo();

    int getI() const;
    void setI(int value);

private:
    int i;
};

#ifndef STATIC_BUILD
#include "foo.cpp"
#endif

#endif // FOO_H
```

foo.cpp

```cpp
#include "foo.h"

MY_INLINE Foo::Foo(){}

MY_INLINE int Foo::getI() const {
    return i;
}

MY_INLINE void Foo::setI(int value) {
    i = value;
}
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "foo.h"

int main() {
    Foo f;
    f.setI(3);
    std::cout << f.getI() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Commenting the line "CONFIG += STATIC_BUILD" in foo.pro and using the class as header only works as expected. 
If I compile this project as static (with the line above not commented) I get "undefined reference" for members of "Foo".

I noticed that, with "CONFIG += STATIC_BUILD" not commented and commenting instead the line

```cpp
#include "foo.cpp"
```

in foo.h, everything works correctly (only for the static build, of course). 
This does not make any sense to me because the "ifndef" has excactly the purpose to do not "compile" the #include in the static build.

What am I doing wrong?

I am using Qt 5.11 with gcc in a linux environment.

Comment: @VTT This does not look like a dupe to me. This looks more like a qmake bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known QMake bug, reported a few times:

- [QTBUG-11923](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-11923).
- [QTBUG-24906](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-24906)
- [QTBUG-57572](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-57572).

*(warning: unnecessary offensive language in the third bug report)*

In short, the mechanism that skips build for a "source file" found to be mentioned in an `#include` directive is not smart enough to consider whether the `#include` directive will actually be executed (that is, it doesn't know about preprocessor conditionals).

Comment: Oof I think they were better separate, @Nikos. Now it doesn't flow

Comment: Feel free to edit as you see fit! Since it turned out it's a known qmake bug, so having more than one answer looks worse to me.

Comment: I'd prefer to keep my answer as it was, but thanks! I did upvote yours btw. Think you should undelete it. Nothing wrong with having multiple perspectives on the same problem; that's why the system can have multiple answers!

Answer (score 2):

This is a known qmake "feature." When it sees:

```
#include "foo.cpp"
```

in the header (regardless of whether it would be "evaluated" or not), it simply doesn't generate build rules for `foo.cpp`, so it's not getting built. Unfortunately, it seems the Qt developers don't view this as a bug, but as a feature.

The workaround is to create a third file (like `foo_incsrc.h`) that only has a single line in it:

```
#include "foo.cpp"
```

and change your `foo.h` accordingly:

```
#ifndef STATIC_BUILD
#include "foo_incsrc.h"
#endif
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes I thought the same thing after losing a lot of time trying to find an error here, but I needed confirmations. I'll report it hoping that it will be fixed asap!